# Failed to open Bucket with transport-couchbase plugin , Elasticsearch with Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, elasticsearch

I am using Couchbase 4.0 Beta and when I try to make a XDCR replication over elastic search server then its constantly giving me

```
< timestamp> : Failed to get bucket user
```

I have followed all the steps that are given,
Please help me out.!!

```
2015-08-17 11:48:24 Failed to get bucket user-account
2015-08-17 11:48:14 Failed to get bucket user-account
2015-08-17 11:48:04 Failed to get bucket user-account
2015-08-17 11:47:54 Failed to get bucket user-account
2015-08-17 11:47:44 Failed to get bucket user-account
2015-08-17 11:47:34 Failed to get bucket user-account
2015-08-17 11:47:24 Failed to get bucket user-account
2015-08-17 11:47:14 Failed to get bucket user-account
2015-08-17 11:47:04 Failed to get bucket user-account
2015-08-17 11:46:54 Failed to get bucket user-account
```

I have added 
transport.couchbase: TRACE
com.couchbase: TRACE

in the logging.yml as suggested on some links.

And the log that I get on the Elastic search is

```
[2015-08-17 11:50:22,323][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:22,323][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:22,323][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:22,323][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,129][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pools
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,129][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pool default
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,130][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,130][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,130][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,130][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,135][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,135][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,135][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:24,135][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:27,276][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pools
[2015-08-17 11:50:27,277][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pool default
[2015-08-17 11:50:27,278][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:27,278][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:27,278][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:27,278][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:32,247][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pools
[2015-08-17 11:50:32,247][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pool default
[2015-08-17 11:50:32,247][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:32,248][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:32,248][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:32,248][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,134][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pools
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,135][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pool default
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,135][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,135][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,135][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,135][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,141][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,141][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,141][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:34,141][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:37,241][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pools
[2015-08-17 11:50:37,242][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pool default
[2015-08-17 11:50:37,242][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:37,242][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:37,243][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:37,243][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:42,261][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pools
[2015-08-17 11:50:42,262][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pool default
[2015-08-17 11:50:42,262][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:42,262][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:42,262][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:42,263][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,140][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pools
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,145][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pool default
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,146][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,146][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,146][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,146][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,151][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,151][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,151][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:44,151][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:47,247][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pools
[2015-08-17 11:50:47,247][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pool default
[2015-08-17 11:50:47,247][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:47,248][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:47,248][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:47,248][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
^C[2015-08-17 11:50:52,240][INFO ][node                     ] [Nomad] stopping ...
[2015-08-17 11:50:52,248][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pools
[2015-08-17 11:50:52,249][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.ClusterMapServlet] asked for pool default
[2015-08-17 11:50:52,254][TRACE][com.couchbase.capi.servlet.BucketMapServlet] asked for bucket list
[2015-08-17 11:50:52,254][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:52,254][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
[2015-08-17 11:50:52,255][DEBUG][transport.couchbase.capi ] [Nomad] found bucket UUID in cache
```

I coud not create a replication, and I want it for implementing the full text search. Please help me out.. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the beta version of Couchbase 4.0. It's already been fixed for the release version. For now, your options are to downgrade to Couchbase 3.0 or wait for the next release of 4.0.